# Can't update mongo array using RESTful api put

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mongodb, express

I'm very new to the MEAN stack and have recently completed a tutorial and have been trying to further develop it out. It's a simple application that uses a RESTful api to update the mongo db.  Now I'm using a put statement to update certain parts of my documents in my collections.  The only problem is when I try to update an array using this put statement I get a 500 error. This is the put statement in my **Server.js** file:

```
app.put('/users/:id', function (req, res) {
      var id = req.params.id;
      console.log(req.body.name);
      db.users.findAndModify({
        query: {_id: mongojs.ObjectId(id)},
        update: {$set: {name: req.body.help.name, email: req.body.email, number:                    req.body.number}},
        new: true}, function (err, doc) {
      res.json(doc);
    }    
  );
});
```

If you notice the `body.email` and `body.number` update statements work great. However I tried making a very simple array to just test the topic. In one of my users documents I have this array.

```
"help" : [ 
        {
            "name" : "test"
        }
    ],
```

All I would like to do is figure out how to change the value in the array. The put statement works great for changing strings in the mongo document but not the array. I noticed that `req.body.string` is how you accessed it so I figured all I would have to do would be to add to it so in this case `req.body.help.name`. However this doesn't work, all I get is a 500 error in my console log. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I think that instead of req.body.help.name you need to use, req.body.help[0].name because you have an array of objects as a value of help object. Otherwhise change it to help : { name: 'value' }. Also be sure that you are recieving the parameters when u print console.log(req.body)

Also, the 500 error that you are viewing is in the browser console? you need to see the "terminal" where your nodjs application is running to see nodejs errors

Comment: Also make sure that you are sending a response back with res.send() or similar methods.. 

But again, review the terminal output in order to see nodejs execution errors, i think that you have an error in the syntax of the update: property after req.body.mail, number: new : true} think that is wrong.

Comment: The error I'm getting in my terminal is Argument passed in must be a single String of 12 bytes or a string of  24 hex characters. I tried both answers and I was unable to get it to work.

Comment: That seems to be related to the line:  query: {_id: mongojs.ObjectId(id)}, assuming that you already google it

Comment: can you write `console.log(err);` before `res.json(doc);` and tell us what exactly the error is?. My guess would be like ecarrizo said `req.body.help[0].name` instead of `req.body.help.name` since you're dealing with an array.

PS: kind of off topic, but personally I'd recommend using `mongoose` for node applications. But I guess, that's a question of personal preference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the answer ended up being that I didn't inculde the array in my $set for the update portion of the findandmodify. Here's what it should look like in the code is : 
     update: {$set: {help: {name: req.body.help.name}}}